не удаётся воспользоваться flask
Есть условный сайт https://xxx.github.io/game/index.html. При попытке взять информацию из файла html index.html через <form>, action="/submit" (форма указана в коде HTML) для файла game.py, меня перебрасывает на страницу https://xxx.github.io/game/index.html/submit, на которой стоит ошибка 405 NOT ALLOWED, вместо того, чтобы использовать данные в файле game.py
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при использовании формы не происходило никакого редиректа на несуществующий сайт?
**Код на python был написан на vscode, где использовался редирект на http://127.0.0.1:5000/submit
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Угадай число</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Угадай число!</h1>
    <h3>Введите число от 1 до 999</h3>
    <form method="post" action="/submit" >
        <input type="text" name="data">
    </form> 
</body>
</html>

PYTHON:
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    global n
    n = int(request.form['data'])
    if n < 1 or n > 999:
        return render_template_string(f'''
        <p>Число {n} не соответствует условию. Введите, пожалуйста, заново!</p>
        <form action="/submit" method="post">
            <input type="number" name="data">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
                                      ''')
    else:
        return render_template_string(f'''
        <p>Попробуйте угадать загаданное число!</p>
        <form action="/guessed_submit" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="guessed_data">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
                                      ''')


@app.route('/guessed_submit', methods=['POST'])
def guess():
    left, right = 0, 999
    guessed_n = int(request.form['guessed_data'])
    while guessed_n != n:
        if guessed_n < right and guessed_n > n:
            right = guessed_n
            return render_template_string(f'''
            <p>Число левее, чем {guessed_n}, попробуйте снова! ;)
            <form action="/guessed_submit" method="post">
                <input type="number" name="guessed_data">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
                                          ''')
        elif guessed_n > left and guessed_n < n:
            left = guessed_n
            return render_template_string(f'''
            <p>Число праве, чем {guessed_n}, попробуйте снова! ;)
            <form action="/guessed_submit" method="post">
                <input type="number" name="guessed_data">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
                                          ''')
        else:
            return render_template_string(f"Не забывайте, что число между {left} и {right}!")
    else:
        return render_template_string(f'''
        <p>Поздравляю! Число {guessed_n} угадано <3
        <form action="/index.html">
            <button type="submit">Вернуться</button>
        </form>
                                      ''')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


В вопросе прямо или косвенно упоминаются целых три разных action, вы уж определитесь какой конкретно action вы используете и где конкретно запущен фласк

спасибо, пропустил этот момент, но вопрос всё ещё не решён) используется action в указанном коде html, и именно он вызывает проблему

action="/submit" никак не может перебрасывать на /game/index.html/submit, вы что-то не договариваете

Но даже если представить, что он перебросит на /submit - в этом всё равно нет смысла, потому что на github.io никакого фласка разумеется нет и быть не может

Всё, ясно! Спасибо большое))
